# MS Access running queries fast sometimes, slow other times

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I've been building a database application (front-ends in Excel, back-end in Access) that stores cash flows from financial models built by modelers (including me) in my group. The database will eventually be quite large (1M+ records would not surprise me), but I've pre-populated it with ~2,500 cash flows linked to ~75 deals (and ~50 clients).

Because there are two-subgroups at my firm, I've actually created two separate back-ends that are now branching due to different requested features (unfortunately). What this did, though, was give me the opportunity to compare run-times for building "temp" tables (or stored queries) off of the permanent tables that show up in a variety of reports. These queries involve a series of joins. All else equal, one database takes about 1 second, the other about 10 seconds despite similar record counts. The former was also operating at 10 seconds previously, but I ended up making some changes to the former's table structure to bring it back in line with the latter's after I updated the latter's. The decrease in load times is really puzzling me, since I didn't do anything other than add a few fields here and there.

The temp table queries are called from VBA in Excel, but just to be sure that it wasn't something in Excel/DAO, I ran the same queries from VBA inside of Access and got similar load times.

Does anybody have any thoughts as to what is going on? I don't want the now-slower database to become unusable at 100,000 records, but it's looking like that might be the case. The faster one, meanwhile, should be okay-ish. I'm pushing to get us on mySQL or SQL Server, but in the meantime this thing will have to shoulder the load.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the indexes?

Comment: And have you compacted both databases?

Comment: Try creating an empty database, then import all objects from the 'slow' database, then run your query again - in the new database.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for the suggestions. Remou, I did that already. HansUp, they're compacting on every close (which I do frequently). @Wayne G. Dunn, I just did that and no change, unfortunately.

Comment: Another option would be to enable SHOWPLAN for your queries (see http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-microsoft-jets-showplan-to-write-more-efficient-queries/) then run the queries in both databases and compare the differences...

Comment: Thanks @WayneG.Dunn. I tried that, but determined that there were no real differences. I then put timers around the queries and figured out that 2 greatest n per group queries are like 99% of the load time for the slower one (still significant for the faster one). I'll post that in the next comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the two queries that is taking forever:

```
sqlCreateGreatestNPerGroupTable = "INSERT INTO zGreatestNPerGroupAlt(UniqueCashFlowID, CashFlowID, DealID, CashFlowType, CashFlowValue, AltOrRef) " & _
                              "SELECT u.UniqueCashFlowID, z.CashFlowID, u.DealID, u.CashFlowType, z.CashFlowValue, z.AltOrRef " & _
                              "FROM UniqueCashFlows as u LEFT JOIN zCashFlowsWithTimes as z ON u.UniqueCashFlowID = z.UniqueCashFlowID " & _
                              "WHERE (z.CashFlowID) " & _
                              "In(SELECT Top 1 z2.CashFlowID FROM zCashFlowsWithTimes as z2 " & _
                              "WHERE z2.UniqueCashFlowID = u.UniqueCashFlowID " & _
                              "AND z2.AltOrRef = 'Alt' " & _
                              "ORDER BY z2.DealUpdateTime DESC);"
```

In short, each UniqueCashFlow has several non-unique CashFlows that "update" it. I want to take the most recent non-unique CashFlow for each UniqueCashflow. Is there a way to speed up this query? Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, I got it. I brought down those queries MASSIVELY in time by using a MAX function on the DealUpdateTime, and then rejoining the non-unique CashFlows with the unique combination of UniqueCashFlowID and DealUpdateTime. Thanks everyone for your help--couldn't have got here without you! Hopefully people can take away the lesson that a WHERE...IN statement is painfully slow in Access, and that alternatives should be preferred.

Comment: If `EXISTS ()` can be used instead of `IN ()`, it may result in huge performance improvements